# Insert post with HTML tags - Wordpress API & PHP

Tags: html, wordpress, api, post, insert

I've a problem with **WP API** to insert a post with HTML Tags.

I'm using the method: **wp_insert_post()** and the content is like this:

```
$content = "Hi, this is an example <br/> of the content.";
```

The result I want when I publish the post is:

```
Hi, this is an example
of the content
```

But the result I have when I publish the post is:

```
Hi, this is an example <br/> of the content.
```

When I go to the WP Editor, The Text editor looks like:

```
Hi, this is an example &lt;br/&gt; of the content.
```

And The Visual Editor:

```
Hi, this is an example <br/> of the content.
```

And obviosly **I want this result** in the Text editor:

```
Hi, this is an example <br/> of the content.
```

And in the Visual Editor:

```
Hi, this is an example
of the content.
```

This happens with all html tags.

Thank you very much.

**** UPDATE WITH THE CODE ****

```
$content="Hi, this is an example <br/> of the content."; 
$my_post = array( 
'post_title' => $title, 
'post_status' => 'publish', 
'post_content' => $content,
'post_author' => 1, 
'post_category' => array(8,39)); 
// Insert the post into the database 
$post_id = wp_insert_post( $my_post );
```

Comment: Please paste some reference of your code. The insert post code.

Comment: `$content="Hi, this is an example <br/> of the content."; $my_post = array(
     'post_title'    => $title,   
     'post_status'   => 'publish',
     'post_content'  => $content
     'post_author'   => 1,
     'post_category' => array(8,39) //meter las categorias
   );

   // Insert the post into the database
   $post_id = wp_insert_post( $my_post );`

Comment: have you found a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a solution:

html_entity_decode($content)

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php

Comment: I dont understand ... html_entity_decode($content) may works when displaing the post ... but the goal is to save uncoded tags in database